# NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings swift equivalent?

Tags: ios, swift

The Apple documentation shows an unsettling blank space under the 'Creating a Dictionary' section of the UIKit reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings).

Has anyone found a replacement for the `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` macro, or are we expected to just write our own?

EDIT - According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html) perhaps the right approach is to write a global function to handle this? Looks like complex macros are out entirely.

Answer (score 61):

According to Apple source code:

> NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(v1, v2, v3) is equivalent to [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:v1, @"v1", v2, @"v2", v3, @"v3", nil];

So in Swift you can do the same using:

```
let bindings = ["v1": v1, "v2": v2, "v3": v3]
```

Comment: Right, but this is a way to write a dictionary in Objective-C also. Funny thing is, they just removed the macro itself...but left the comment defining it in Swift (check the code if you open up Swift's NSLayoutConstraint). I really just don't like writing my variable names twice, especially since you could misspell it in the key and cause crashes. It's a minor annoyance, but it is an annoyance.

Comment: According to the XCode 6 beta 2 release notes, Dictionary is not yet bridged to NSDictionary. Until that happens, you'll probably want to explicitly create a NSDictionary or NSMutable dictionary with those values. Using a native Swift dictionary as a parameter to 
constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views: currently causes a crash.

Comment: @JohnM.P.Knox It is not a matter of Dictionary being bridged to NSDictionary. It _is_ bridged; of course it's bridged! Passing a native Swift dictionary works perfectly here. That's not the problem. The problem is that there are _no macros_ and you can't "introspect" a variable name, so there can be no equivalent of `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings`.

Comment: @Stakenborg They did not "remove the macro but left the comment". There are no Swift headers! You are looking at the Objective-C header (passed through a spontaneous live-generated translation into Swift). The macro is simply not translated because there are no macros in Swift.

Answer (score 28):

`NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings` is, as you say, a macro. There are no macros in Swift. So much for that.

Nonetheless, you can easily write a Swift function to assign string names to your views in a dictionary, and then pass that dictionary into `constraintsWithVisualFormat`. The difference is that, unlike Objective-C, Swift can't see *your* names for those views; you will have to let it *make up* some *new* names.

[To be clear, it isn't that your Objective-C *code* could see your variable names; it's that, at macro evaluation time, the preprocessor was operating on your source code *as text* and rewriting it — and so it could just use the text of your variable names both inside quotes (to make strings) and outside (to make values) to form a dictionary. But with Swift, there is no preprocessor.]

So, here's what I do:

```
func dictionaryOfNames(arr:UIView...) -> Dictionary<String,UIView> {
    var d = Dictionary<String,UIView>()
    for (ix,v) in arr.enumerate(){
        d["v\(ix+1)"] = v
    }
    return d
}
```

And you call it and use it like this:

```
    let d = dictionaryOfNames(myView, myOtherView, myFantasicView)
    myView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|[v2]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: d)
    )
```

The catch is that it is *up to you* to realize that the name for `myOtherView` in your visual format string will be `v2` (because it was second in the list passed in to `dictionaryOfNames()`). But I can live with that just to avoid the tedium of typing out the dictionary by hand every time.

Of course, you could equally have written more or less this same function in Objective-C. It's just that you didn't bother because the macro already existed!

Comment: Please use `NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0)` instead of `nil` for `options:` parameter (XCode 7 Swift 2.0)

Comment: @Maverick Uh, no. Nobody would say `NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0)`. You just say `options:[]` in Swift 2.

Comment: Yikes. I'd definitely be worried about mistakes with this. I.e., plopping a view into the dictionary somewhere other than at the end and thereby breaking all sorts of constraints. But, as you said, it's up to the dev to understand the naming convention.

Comment: @stuckj Fortunately, now that we have the anchor notation along with stack views, reasons for using the visual format are few and far between these days. :)

Answer (score 2):

That functionality is based on macro expansion which is currently not supported in Swift.

I do not think there is any way to do something similar in Swift at the moment. I believe you cannot write your own replacement.

I'm afraid you'll have to manually unroll the dictionary definition, even if it means repeating each name twice.

Answer (score 2):

So I hacked something together which seems to work:

```
func dictionaryOfVariableBindings(container: Any, views:UIView...) -> Dictionary<String, UIView> {
    var d = Dictionary<String, UIView>()
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: container)
    let _ = mirror.children.compactMap {
        guard let name = $0.label, let view = $0.value as? UIView else { return }
        guard views.contains(view) else { return }
        d[name] = view
    }
    return d
}
```

Usage:

```
        let views = dictionaryOfVariableBindings(container: self, views: imageView)
```

Comment: You are a god.  I've tested this under Xcode 10.2.1 and it works.  I'll post a modified version based off of your code that is an extension of UIViewController, so we can assume self as the container.

Answer (score 1):

ObjC runtime to the rescue!

i created an alternate solution, but it only works if each of the views are instance variables of the same object.

```
func DictionaryOfInstanceVariables(container:AnyObject, objects: String ...) -> [String:AnyObject] {
    var views = [String:AnyObject]()
    for objectName in objects {
        guard let object = object_getIvar(container, class_getInstanceVariable(container.dynamicType, objectName)) else {
            assertionFailure("\(objectName) is not an ivar of: \(container)");
            continue
        }
        views[objectName] = object
    }
    return views
}
```

can be used like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var childA: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return view
    }()

    var childB: UIButton = {
        let view = UIButton()
        view.setTitle("asdf", forState: .Normal)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.addSubview(childA)
        self.view.addSubview(childB)

        let views = DictionaryOfInstanceVariables(self, objects: "childA", "childB")
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[childA]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[childB]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[childA][childB(==childA)]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))

    }

}
```

unfortunately you still have to type the variable name in as a string, but it will at least assert if there is a typo. this definitely won't work in all situations, but helpful nonetheless

Comment: Worth noting for your solution: these views must be stored as an iVar of an object-c object.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/55086673/1058199 by cherpak-evgeny, this UIViewController extension assumes that the container is `self`, the current viewController instance.

```
extension UIViewController {

    // Alex Zavatone 06/04/2019
    // Using reflection, get the string name of the UIView properties passed in
    // to create a dictionary of ["viewPropertyName": viewPropertyObject…] like
    // Objective-C's NSDictionaryForVariableBindings.
    func dictionaryOfBindings(_ arrayOfViews:[UIView?]) -> Dictionary<String, UIView> {
        var bindings = Dictionary<String, UIView>()
        let viewMirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        let _ = viewMirror.children.compactMap {
            guard let name = $0.label, let view = $0.value as? UIView else { return }
            guard arrayOfViews.contains(view) else { return }
            bindings[name] = view
        }
        return bindings
    }
}
```

Use it like so from within your viewController:

```
let viewArray = [mySwitch, myField, mySpinner, aStepper, someView]
let constraintsDictionary = dictionaryOfBindings(viewArray)
```

Tested in Xcode 10.2.1 and Swift 4.2.

Many thanks to [Cherpak Evgeny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320010/cherpak-evgeny) for writing it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've stored all your views as properties, you could also use reflection like so:

```
extension ViewController {
    func views() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        var views = dictionaryOfProperties()
        views.forEach {
            if !($1 is UIView) {
                views[$0] = nil
            }
        }
        return views
    }
}

extension NSObject {

    func dictionaryOfProperties() -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        var result = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        for case let(label?, value) in mirror.children {
            result[label] = value as? AnyObject
        }
        return result
    }
}
```